# jquery form slider (input-slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, slider

How to make slider with jquery, like here?

[image: sample]

User should select a value from slider, and this value should automatically be in input

I can not find the appropriate plug-in...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

```
 $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
                           //Its setting the slider value to the element with id "amount"
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
```

You can customize the style to look like the example you mentioned.

Comment: @IlyaMedvedev Doesn't this code do the opposite of what you requested. It is setting the slider value while you wanted to use the slider to set a different input?

Comment: @user1850672 : The line `$( "#amount" ).val...` will set the selected value from slider to the input box, which is what the OP was looking for