# Get value from jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm creating kind of a registration form, and I've used the FORM tag for names and so on, and I also need sliders. I've created my sliders with jquery.
Is there any way I can "forward" values from this sliders, as I will from FORM tag inputs, for php script?
Thanks

```
<p style="text-align: center">Amount: <span id="amountDisp" style="color: #ff0000">500</span><div id="amount_slider"></div></p>

function () {
$("#amount_slider").slider({
            handle: "myhandle",
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: false,
    min: 500,
    max: 4999,
    value: 500,
    step: 1,
            animate: true,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").text(ui.value);
        calculate();
    },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amountDisp").text(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes why not submitting the form to the target php page. try to get the slider values in a hidden input.

Comment: what slider? o.O Post the code please.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630069/jquery-form-slider-input-slider)

Comment: Post some code. You can send slider indexes through post jquery method to a php file.... Post you code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post values to php on server you need some textfield that holds value when slider changed. You can use hidden input. Set value in this hidden input and that'll be posted along with other form elements.

Change html to following --

```
<p style="text-align: center">
   Amount: <span id="amountDisp" style="color: #ff0000">500</span>
   <div id="amount_slider"></div>
   <input type="text" id="amount_field">
</p>
```

I didn't used `hidden` input for demo purpose and change js to --

```
$("#amount_slider").slider({
    handle: "myhandle",
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: false,
    min: 500,
    max: 4999,
    value: 500,
    step: 1,
    animate: true,
    change: function (event, ui) {       
        $("#amount_field").val(ui.value);
        $("#amountDisp").text(ui.value);
        calculate();
    },
     slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount_field").val(ui.value);
        $("#amountDisp").text(ui.value);        
    }
});
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RvEXD/3/)

**UPDATE**

If in case you are using `ajax` for submit form, you can directly pick value from `amountDisp` with -

```
var sliderAmount = $("#amountDisp").text();
```

Comment: And btw. What does this elem. value do? Why have you changed it?

Comment: @jevniky Sory, thats should not be `elem`. CHange it to `ui`. I've updated fiddle also.